# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.mycalculator.RegistersApp

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

The complete line in the log is:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mycalculator/com.example.mycalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.mycalculator.RegistersApp`.

I am trying to add `Room` storage to a calculator app. The code for the `Room` is recycled from another app and I'm fairly certain all of the vars and such have been updated to fit, but..... The log mentions the `RegistersApp`, so here it is:

```
package com.example.mycalculator

import android.app.Application

class RegistersApp: Application() {

    val db by lazy {
        RegistersDatabase.getInstance(this)
    }
  }
```

After much testing I have found that the app crashes with this offending line in the onCreate:

`val registersDao = (application as RegistersApp).db.registersDao()`

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if any other code is needed, please let me know. Needless to say this is my 1st Room experience.

Thanks,
Ray.

Comment: Did you remember to set your `RegistersApp` as the `android:name` on the `<application>` element in the manifest?

Comment: That was it Mike. Now that is solved. Thank you.

Comment: @Ray how did you solve this?